# json_encode() behavior for public properties

Tags: php, json, serialization

I know this works:

```php
<?php 

class MyDTO 
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}

$dto = new MyDTO();
$dto->foo = 42;
$dto->bar = false;

echo json_encode($dto); // {"foo": 42, "bar": false}
```

But I cannot find any references to such `json_encode()` behavior in the PHP docs. So my question: is it ok to rely on it?

Alternatively, I can implement `\JsonSerializable` interface, but I don't like to repeat DTO fields inside `\JsonSerializable#jsonSerialize()` considering those DTOs will contain only public fields.

Comment: Yes, you can trust that behavior. I only implement JsonSerializable if I want to modify the response in some way, or add non-public params to the response.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Any chance you have any additional references for this?

Comment: Nothing on print I can point to now, but I've been using that function (with objects) since it was introduced, and if it would change the behavior, it would cause havoc in the PHP community. And since that function is for getting a json representation of a value, it can't really work in any other way.